# scrollView shadow expands to content size when adding shadow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, calayer

I have a scrollView which has an `origin.y = -200`, `size.height = 200` and `contentSize.height = 270`.

On the main view I have a `tableView` with the touch of a `button`. the `scrollView` animates from the **top** to `origin.y = 64`. Because the `scrollView` and `tableView` share the same color background, I want a shadow outside the the `scrollView` to make the views separate.

But when I set the `scrollView.layer.masksToBounds = YES` it automatically expands to its full `contentSize` which is **270**. If I comment out the `maskToBounds` I get no shadow. What am I missing? Thank you in advance

```
_addScroller.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
_addScroller.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2);
_addScroller.layer.shadowOpacity = .7f;
_addScroller.layer.shadowRadius = 2;
//    _addScroller.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
CGPathRef path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:_addScroller.frame].CGPath;
_addScroller.layer.shadowPath = path;
```

This is with masksToBounds = NO;
it automatically sets the frame.height to the contentSize.height
[image]

Comment: Can you add screen shot?

Comment: added the screenShot for you @jai

Answer (score 0):

What if you add the scrollview inside another view (of the same size as the scrollview, i.e. 200px height) and set the container view's shadow and maskToBounds?

I think a similar situation is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690972/why-maskstobounds-yes-prevents-calayer-shadow).

Comment: I have already seen that post and I have considered that option. But why it automatically adjusts to the contentSize?

Comment: Not sure but adding scrollView inside a container view seems to be a rather common way of doing things, at least according to e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091998/how-to-mask-a-uiscrollview) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709543/mask-overlay-on-uiscrollview).